# QGLWidget is slower than QWidget

Tags: qt, opengl, windows-7-x64

The problem mainly is determined in the title. I tried out the Qt's example ([2dpainting](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/opengl-2dpainting.html)) and noticed, that the same code consumes more CPU power if I try to draw on QGLWidget and less if I try to draw simply on QWidget. I thought that the QGLWidget should be faster. And one more interesting phenomenon: In QGLWidget the antialiasing hint seems to be ignored.

OpenGL version: 3.3.0

So why is that?

Comment: CPU load, as reported by the operating system is a total sham. All it reports is the amount of time your process spends doing work during its allocated timeslice. If you draw with no VSYNC or any other sort of frame limiting mechanism, in OpenGL you can easily achieve 100% CPU utilization without actually doing anything particularly complicated on the CPU. You just happen to be using the CPU for the entire amount of time the OS offered it to you. Enable VSYNC or throttle your drawing and your CPU usage should go down, you might need to do `Sleep (0)` after `SwapBuffers (...)` on Windows.

Comment: As for the anti-aliasing hint... in modern OpenGL, you need an MSAA pixel format for API-based anti-aliasing. Polygon/Line/Point smoothing is not often supported by hardware / APIs anymore, so if this is what you are referring to as a hint then that comes as no surprise. Even when it is, it requires a lot of extra setup, like an alpha buffer, special considerations for sorting geometry and a special blend function.

Comment: Actually in the example is built in a timing mechanism, which notifies the widget in frequent intervals (approx. 0.05 s) when to draw the next image.

Comment: QTimer is used in both cases. I think, the Qt built-in libraries are smarter than a spin-lock. (To be more precise: one class -- or thread, I think -- notifies the other after every 0.05 s).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, note this text at the bottom of the documentation that you link to:

> The example shows the same painting operations performed at the same
>   time in a Widget and a GLWidget. The quality and speed of rendering in
>   the GLWidget depends on the level of support for multisampling and
>   hardware acceleration that your system's OpenGL driver provides. If
>   support for either of these is lacking, the driver may fall back on a
>   software renderer that may trade quality for speed.

Putting that aside, hardware rendering is not always guaranteed to be faster than software rendering; it all depends upon what the renderer is being asked to do.

An example of where software can exceed hardware is if the goal of the item being rendered is constantly changing. So, if you have a drawing program that draws a line being created by the mouse being constantly moved and it is implemented by adding points to a painter path that is drawn every frame, a hardware renderer will be subject to constant pipeline stalls as new points are added to the painter path. Setting up the graphics pipeline from a stall takes time, which is not something a software renderer has to deal with.

In the 2dPainting example you ask about, the helper class, which performs the paint calls, is doing a lot of unnecessary work; saving the painter state; setting the pen / brush; rotating the painter; restoring the brush. All of this is a bigger overhead in hardware than software. To really see hardware rendering outperform software, pre-calculating the objects' positions outside of the render loop (paint function) and then doing nothing put actually rendering in the paint function is likely to display a noticeable difference here.

Finally, regarding anti-aliasing, the documentation that you linked to states: "the QGLWidget will also use anti-aliasing if the required extensions are supported by your system's OpenGL driver"