# What is the most efficient to draw out a grid?

Tags: c++, qt

I need a grid on a QGraphicsView, and i update my canvas every 35ms. 
How can i generate a grid with the best performance?

I'm using this now:

```
//vertical lines
    for(double i = 0; i < global::circuitWidth; i+= global::gridSize)
    {
        painter->drawLine(global::mmToPixel(i-global::circuitCornerX), -            global::mmToPixel(global::circuitCornerY),   global::mmToPixel(i-global::circuitCornerX), global::mmToPixel(global::circuitHeight-global::circuitCornerY));
    }
    //horizontal lines
    for(double i = 0; i < global::circuitHeight; i+= global::gridSize)
    {
        painter->drawLine(-global::mmToPixel(global::circuitCornerX), global::mmToPixel(i-global::circuitCornerY), global::mmToPixel(global::circuitWidth-global::circuitCornerX), global::mmToPixel(i-global::circuitCornerY));
    }
```

Now i realized that i can calculate a few parameters before, but any other than that? Maybe create an image an draw out that instead lines?

And also is there a way to boost QT's graphics performance with some settings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8280539/5653461

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the grid doesn't change, build it up in with a [QPainterPath](http://If%20the%20grid%20doesn't%20change,%20then%20you%20can%20build%20it%20up%20in%20a%20[QPainterPath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html)) and just draw that.

> is there a way to boost QT's graphics performance with some settings?

Yes, there are several ways, though it depends on what you're doing. Using [openGL](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-index.html#opengl-and-opengl-es-integration) is often much faster, though [not always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234191/qglwidget-is-slower-than-qwidget/19242579#19242579).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to use openGL with QPainter and QGraphicsView?

Comment: Yes, see here [this discussion](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/40987-QGraphicsScene-OpenGL-rendering) for examples for setting a QGLWidget on the viewport